# edit profile dont worked :/ laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i have problem, when i want to edit my profile in laravel. When i click button update profile have this error : 
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile

edit.blade.php

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Update Profile
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.edit') }}">
                        @method('patch')
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $user->name) }}" autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="pseudo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('pseudo') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="pseudo" type="text" class="form-control @error('pseudo') is-invalid @enderror" name="pseudo" value="{{ old('pseudo', $user->pseudo) }}" autocomplete="pseudo" autofocus>

                                @error('pseudo')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email', $user->email) }}" autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Update Profile
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/chats', 'ChatController@index')->name('chats');
Route::get('/messages', 'ChatController@fetchAllMessages');
Route::get('/messages', 'ChatController@sendMessage');

Route::get('/contacts', 'ContactsController@get');
Route::get('/conversation/{id}', 'ContactsController@getMessagesFor');
Route::get('/conversation/send', 'ContactsController@send');


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
});
```

Profile controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the update profile page.
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        return view('profile.edit', [
            'user' => $request->user()
        ]);
    }
}
```

someone can help resolve this error pls. I don't understand what is the problem.

passwordChange.blade.php i created this page for try if change password worked and in other page it's worked but when i try in one page in edit profile, dont worked.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Laravel - Change Password with Current</div>
   
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile') }}">
                        @csrf 
   
                         @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <p class="text-danger">{{ $error }}</p>
                         @endforeach 
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Current Password</label>
  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="current_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">New Password</label>
  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">New Confirm Password</label>
    
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new_confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_confirm_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
   
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Update Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

When i try to do this in differents pages it's worked, i created other page changePassword.blade.php and when i change password in this page its worked, and when i try update profile when i leave password route etc... its worked too, but when i want to change all in one page i have this error

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: user (View: /home/mokoch/Bureau/projetabonnementpayant/resources/views/profile/edit.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile

If someone can help me resole this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in your route, says it is a GET request only

```
Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
```

Your form says method="POST"

you can change your Route to "any", that will allow get and post

```
Route::any('profile', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
```

Comment: `Route::any` allows **ALL** methods, if you want to do only *GET* and *POST*, you should do `Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'profile', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profile.edit');`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your form you are telling Laravel that it is a patch request with this line

```
@method('patch')
```

But in your routes file you are only looking for a get method

```
Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
```

If you are sending as a patch then you would need an additional line

```
Route::patch('profile', 'ProfileController@update');
```

Then you would need to create an update method in your controller to handle the save logic

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        // Logic to update
    }
```

Comment: When i try to do this in differents pages it's worked, i created other page changePassword.blade.php and when i change password in this page its worked, and when i try update profile when i leave password route etc... its worked too, but when i want to change all in one page i have this error